# R mutate and map: pass the object linked to .?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

In a typical case where I use `map`:

```
out <- map(data_list, ~fo(arg1 =.))
```

if `fo()` returns the call to the function (like in `out[[1]]$call`), it will contain `arg1=.`, but this is likely to cause problems if the `call` output is re-used later on (example below). How can I have instead something like `arg1=data_list[[1]]`, i.e. the `.` is evaluated (or passed to, not sure how to call that)?

**Example:** run `lm()` regressions with map, with `data=.`, i.e. `map(data, ~lm(f, data = .))`. Try then to update the regressions. This will not work as `update()` will look for `out$call$data` and find `.`, so won't know where to look for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_nest <-  nest(as_tibble(iris), -Species)
regs <- map(iris_nest$data, ~lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = .))

# update first?
update(regs[[1]], ~ . - Sepal.Width)
#> Error in is.data.frame(data): object '.' not found

## issue comes from:
regs[[1]]$call$data
#> .
```

Workaround: the workaround I have is to feed back ex-post the `out$call$data`, but hopefully there is a better way to do this ex-ante, with some `eval`/`get`/

```r
# workaround:
regs[[1]]$call$data <- iris_nest$data[[1]]
update(regs[[1]], ~ . - Sepal.Width)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = structure(list(
#>     Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 5, 4.4, 
#>     3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 
#> SKIP SKIP SKIP
#>     0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", 
#> "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), row.names = c(NA, 
#> -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
#>       4.2132        0.5423
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a linear regression model with update and purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590037/updating-a-linear-regression-model-with-update-and-purrr)

Comment: thanks for the pointer, that's similar indeed, except that my goal is to pass the data/environment to the lm() function, instead of having to refer back to the data?

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

To update `lm` objects in a nested data frame, you need to explicitly reference the data that contains the variables used in [`stats::update()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.html) to re-fit the linear model. You can do this by using [`purrr::map2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) to supply both the `lm` object and the `data` object.

## Code

```
# load necessary package ----
library(tidyverse)

# load necessary data ----
iris_nest <-
  iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  # lm1 = perform linear regression for each Species
  # lm2 = update lm1 for each Species 
  #       by removing Sepal.Width from the regression
  # note: use of map2() required to explicitly reference
  #       the data being used in lm()
  mutate(lm1 = map(.x = data
                   , .f = ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length
                               , data = .))
         , lm2 = map2(.x = lm1
                      , .y = data
                      , .f = ~ update(object = .x
                                      , formula. = ~ . - Sepal.Width
                                      , data = .y)))

# inspect results ---
iris_nest$lm1[[1]] %>% coefficients()
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 
#   2.3037382    0.6674162    0.2834193

iris_nest$lm2[[1]] %>% coefficients()
# (Intercept) Petal.Length 
#   4.2131682    0.5422926 

# end of script #
```